# Cloud Build: using with a monorepo

Tags: google-cloud-build

I have a [repo](http://github.com/akauppi/GroundLevel-firebase-es) with three rather independent subpackages:

```
- packages
  - backend
  - app
  - app-deploy-ops
```

Cloud Build samples show only a single `cloudbuild.yaml`.

Would the strategy to make a repo like this CI/CD-able (run tests on PRs, for example, but relevant tests based on what changed), involve making three build definitions? That's the only approach I can think of. Then pick those in the Cloud Build triggers, as appropriate.

My question likely is: am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have only one trigger with all your code in Cloud Build and customize only one big `cloudbuild.yaml` file to build only the relevant part.

The other option is to create a trigger per part of your project. the `cloudbuild.yaml` file is in each subdir of your code (you can precise that in the trigger) and thus the file is smaller and dedicated to the part to build.

I recommend you the 2nd approach, but yes, you need 3 files and to define 3 triggers.